# Bash/Zsh - Export environment variable with name containing a colon

Tags: bash, environment-variables, zsh

I'm trying to set the following environment variable in bash:

> ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection=someValue

I'm using the following command:

`export ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection=something`

In bash I get the following error:

`export: 'ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection=something': not a valid identifier`

And in zsh the following error:

`export: not valid in this context: ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection`

How can I set an environment variable whose variable name contains a colon?

Comment: I don't think you can do that in `bash`

Comment: Since colon has a special meaning?

Comment: Variable names in bash can only contain alphanumerics or an underscore, and cannot start with a numeric.  See also http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html

Comment: This is a common question but I can't find a good duplicate on Stack Overflow proper. The common workaround is `env ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection=something bash`

Comment: So I happened to arrive at this page because I'm using .NET Core in a docker container using environment variables with colons, and the app is being started from a shell script. The shell script removes the environment variables because it doesn't like them. The fix for me is to use the alternate supported format of colon to double underscore, which .NET Core graciously supports. For this `ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection` becomes `ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bash doesn't support such names but you can create them with external programs like `env` or `python`.

#### Using env

The command `env` will set an environment and run another command.  For example, here we use `env` to run `printenv`:

```
$ env a:b=3 printenv | grep ^a
a:b=3
```

`env` can also be used to run a new shell:

```
$ env a:b=4 bash
$ printenv | grep ^a
a:b=4
```

(Hat tip: [Chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner)).

#### Using python

Python allows manipulation of the environment.  This python script creates environment variables with colons and then runs an instance of `bash`:

```
$ cat colon.py
#!/bin/python 
import os
import subprocess
os.environ['a:b'] = 'c'
os.environ['ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection'] = 'someValue'
subprocess.call('bash')
```

If we run the above script, we will get a new bash prompt.  At the new prompt, we can verify that the variables exist:

```
$ printenv | grep -E 'Connection|a:b'
ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection=someValue
a:b=c
```

#### Environment variable names that bash supports

Unless one has a very good reason to want nonconforming variable names, it is much easier to use variable names that bash supports.  That would include names that start with a letter or underline followed by zero or more alphanumeric characters or underlines.

Comment: Nice hack. Though I'll take your advice and pick a simpler variable name! Thanks

Comment: Neat trick! But why would want that not doable in `bash`? may be they don't want to support such a convention? Don't you think in such a case it is not wise to recommend such usage?

Comment: `bash` doesn't provide arbitrary access to the environment, only to those names which are valid shell identifiers. You can use the `env` command to add other names to an environment if needed. `env a:b=3 commandThatUsesA:B`